# very slow query using web sql and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

Hi i'm working on phonegap app, and im having problem with web sql query. I have a list.html when i draw a table with images that recived from a sql query in a BD.js but i must use setTimeOut on list.html for succes the query, if i dont do it the result if empty.

This is the list.html, on line 38 is the function:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/lista.css">
<script src="../libs/jquery.mobile/jquery-1.7.2.min"></script>
  <script src="../libs/jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../libs/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../libs/jquery.blockUI.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="../libs/cordova-1.9.0.js"></script>
    <script src="../libs/SQLitePlugin.js"></script>
    <script src="../libs/qunit-1.5.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/BDTablaPictogramas.js"></script>
  <script src="../libs/lawnchair-0.6.1.js"></script>
  <script src="../libs/webkit-sqlite.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

      var btnMenuOpcionesPulsado = false,
        dialogoAcercaDe = false;
    var posicionCategoria = 0, numElemCategoria = 0;
    var idioma = "", fraseBuscar = "";
    var listaPictogramas = [];


    $(function(){
      $("#dialogoAcercaDe").hide();
           $("#menuOpciones").hide();
      var todoURL = leerGET();
      posicionCategoria = todoURL['pos'];
      numElemCategoria = todoURL['numElemCategoria'];
      idioma = todoURL['idioma'];
      fraseBuscar = todoURL['fraseBuscar'];
      $.blockUI({ message: '<h1>Cargando...</h1>' });
      var msToWait2 = 11000;
      setTimeout(function() {
      $.unblockUI();
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", cargarImgsCategorias, false);
      }, msToWait2);


         });
    function leerGET(){
      var cadGET = location.search.substr(1, location.search.length);
       var arrGET = cadGET.split("&");
        var asocGET = new Array();
        var variable = "";
        var valor = "";
        for(i=0;i<arrGET.length;i++){
          var aux = arrGET[i].split("=");
          variable = aux[0];
          valor = aux[1];
          asocGET[variable] = valor;
        }
      return asocGET;
    }

    function cargarImgsCategorias(){
      if(posicionCategoria == 0)      loadImgBuscarUnidimensional(fraseBuscar, idioma);
      else if(posicionCategoria == 1)    loadImgFavoritoUnidimensional(idioma);
      else if(posicionCategoria == 2)    loadImgUnidimensional("alimentos");
      else if(posicionCategoria == 3)    loadImgUnidimensional("animales");
      else if(posicionCategoria == 4)    loadImgUnidimensional("animales-insectos");
      else if(posicionCategoria == 5)    loadImgUnidimensional("banno");
      else if(posicionCategoria == 6)    loadImgUnidimensional("cocina");
      else if(posicionCategoria == 7)    loadImgUnidimensional("dormitorio");
      else if(posicionCategoria == 8)    loadImgUnidimensional("miscel_a_nea");
      else if(posicionCategoria == 9)    loadImgUnidimensional("ropa");
      else if(posicionCategoria == 10)  loadImgUnidimensional("sal_o_n");
      else if(posicionCategoria == 11)  loadImgUnidimensional("transportes");
      else if(posicionCategoria == 12)  loadImgUnidimensional("varios-hogar");


      var msToWait = 250;
      setTimeout(function() {
        listaPictogramas = getImgsCategoria();
        crearCuadricula();
        hacerClic();
        cargarIdiomaBarraAtras();
        cargarIdiomaAcercaDe();
          cargarIdiomaMenuOpciones();
      }, msToWait);
    }

    function crearCuadricula(){
      for(var i=0;i<numElemCategoria;i++){
        if(i%3 == 0)
          $("table").append('<tr></tr>');
        $("table tr:last-child").append("<td class='focus'><img src='"+listaPictogramas[i]+"' /></td>");
      }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="dialogoAcercaDe">
    <div id="contenido"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="cajaAtras">
    <div id="subcajaAtras1"><img id="btnVolverAtras" src="../images/btn_atras2.png" height="32" width="32" /></div>
    <!-- <div id="subcajaAtras2"><img id="btnMenu" src="../images/menu3.png" height="69" width="128" /></div> -->
    <div id="subcajaAtras2"><img id="btnMenu" src="../images/rueda.png" /></div>
  </div>
  <div id="menuOpciones">
    <ul>
      <li id="opcion1IdiomaESP">Idioma - ESP</li>
      <li id="opcion2IdiomaENG">Idioma - ENG</li>
        <li id="opcion3Acercade">Acerca de...</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="cuadricula">
    <table width="200" border="2" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bordercolor="#000000">
<!--       <tr>
        <td><img src="../assets/imagenes/alimentos/aced_i_as.gif" /></td>
        <td><img src="../assets/imagenes/alimentos/aceitera.gif" /></td>
        <td><img src="../assets/imagenes/alimentos/aceitunas.gif" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><img src="../assets/imagenes/alimentos/acelga.gif" /></td>
        <td><img src="../assets/imagenes/alimentos/ajo.gif" /></td>
        <td><img src="../assets/imagenes/alimentos/albondigas.gif" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><img src="../assets/imagenes/alimentos/alcachofa.gif" /></td>
        <td><img src="../assets/imagenes/alimentos/almejas.gif" /></td>
        <td><img src="../assets/imagenes/alimentos/almendra.gif" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><img src="../assets/imagenes/alimentos/almuerzo.gif" /></td>
        <td><img src="../assets/imagenes/alimentos/alubias.gif" /></td>
        <td><img src="../assets/imagenes/alimentos/anacardos.gif" /></td>
      </tr> -->
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is BD.JS code, the fuction is on line 42

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", initDB, false);
var db = "";

function initDB() {
    try {
        if(!window.openDatabase)
            alert('not supported');
        else{
            var shortName = 'Pictogramas';
            var version = '1.0';
            var displayName = 'PhoneGap Pictogramas Database';
            var maxSize = 9999999999;   // en bytes
            db = window.openDatabase(shortName, version, displayName, maxSize);
            db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
        }
    }catch(e){
        if(e == INVALID_STATE_ERR)
            alert("Invalid database version.");
        else
            alert("Unknown error "+e+".");
        return;
    }
}

function populateDB(tx) {

    var BDCreada = localStorage.getItem('BDTablaPictogramasCreada') || '<empty>';
    if(BDCreada != "SI"){
//se cren las tablas y las inserciones
BDCreada = "SI";
        localStorage.setItem("BDTablaPictogramasCreada", BDCreada);
        alert("AVISO BD FINAL");
function errorCB(err) {
    alert("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);  
}

function successCB() {
  console.log("Success creating Database 1.0");
  console.log("Rows Affected = " + results.rowAffected);
  alert("Creada con exito.");
}
//Función que no se ejecuta sino se espera 11 segundos.
function loadImgUnidimensional(categoria){
    db.transaction
    (
        function (tx){
          //alert("Posición:"+categoria);
            tx.executeSql
            (

              "SELECT RutaImagen FROM Pictogramas WHERE Categoria = '"+categoria+"'",

                [],
                function(tx,results){
                   var len = results.rows.length;
                    for(var i=0;i<len;i++)
                        imgsCategoria.push(results.rows.item(i).RutaImagen);

                }, errorCB
            );
        },errorCB,successCB
    );
return imgsCategoria;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your callback

```
           function function(tx,results){
               var len = results.rows.length;
                for(var i=0;i<len;i++)
                    imgsCategoria.push(results.rows.item(i).RutaImagen);

            }
```

call a function of your own that resumes your program flow.

How it should be:

1. Function one -> does its thing, executes query
2. Function two -> handles query output(the above function in this case). This function calls function three after its done.
3. Function three -> resumes program flow

Comment: I dont understand how i must do to sleep html file until the function javascript finish.

Thanks for answer.

Comment: you cannot sleep the html.

Comment: The problem is that fuction  crearCuadricula();  in html file is execute before the query is finish ( i think) then dont know can i solve that.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i solve with a while bucle :

```
function cargarImgsCategorias(){
        if(posicionCategoria == 0)          loadImgBuscarUnidimensional(fraseBuscar, idioma);
        else if(posicionCategoria == 1)     loadImgFavoritoUnidimensional(idioma);
        else if(posicionCategoria == 2)     loadImgUnidimensional("alimentos");
        else if(posicionCategoria == 3)     loadImgUnidimensional("animales");
        else if(posicionCategoria == 4)     loadImgUnidimensional("animales-insectos");
        else if(posicionCategoria == 5)     loadImgUnidimensional("banno");
        else if(posicionCategoria == 6)     loadImgUnidimensional("cocina");
        else if(posicionCategoria == 7)     loadImgUnidimensional("dormitorio");
        else if(posicionCategoria == 8)     loadImgUnidimensional("miscel_a_nea");
        else if(posicionCategoria == 9)     loadImgUnidimensional("ropa");
        else if(posicionCategoria == 10)    loadImgUnidimensional("sal_o_n");
        else if(posicionCategoria == 11)    loadImgUnidimensional("transportes");
        else if(posicionCategoria == 12)    loadImgUnidimensional("varios-hogar");


        var msToWait = 250;
        setTimeout(function() {
            listaPictogramas = getImgsCategoria();
            while(listaPictogramas.length==0){
                cargarImgsCategorias();
                Log.e("esperando","esperando");
            }
            crearCuadricula();
            hacerClic();
            cargarIdiomaBarraAtras();
            cargarIdiomaAcercaDe();
            cargarIdiomaMenuOpciones();
        }, msToWait);
    }
```

Is very strange cause if i quit Log.e dont working, only working with Log.e and i must wait only 1 second.